# ps does not work after upgrading to 14.04 (/usr/bin/dpkgd/ps: error while loading shared libraries)

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, upgrade, ps, rootkit

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04, now on starting my terminal and running `ps` throws the following error :

> /usr/bin/dpkgd/ps: error while loading shared libraries: libproc-3.2.8.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How can this be resolved?

Comment: There are a couple of references out there that suggest the existence of `/usr/bin/dpkgd/ps` and friends may indicate an exploit: [Fedora 21: Getting “libprocps.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory” on ps](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207564/fedora-21-getting-libprocps-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file) and [An in-depth analysis of SSH attacks on Amazon EC2](https://blog.smarthoneypot.com/in-depth-analysis-of-ssh-attacks-on-amazon-ec2/)

Comment: @steeldriver read through the links and it does look like an exploit. But, I've always updated from the package manager and this is a personal machine, any idea how it can be resolved?

Answer (score -1):

When I update 12.04 to 14.04, the same problem. Finally solve it by following command.

```
sudo apt-get install procps
ln -s /bin/ps /usr/bin/ps
```